# Pasar variable a categórica

Tags: r

Tengo un data frame con distintas variables cuantitativas y quiero pasarlas a categóricas. Por ejemplo, la variable Education puede tomar los valores:
'Below College'
'College'
'Bachelor'
'Master'
'Doctor'

Quiero que Education pase a tener un valor numérico, de forma que sea 1 cuando tenga el valor'Below College', 2 cuando sea 'College', 3 con 'Bachelor', etc. Actualmente es una variable tipo integer e imagino que pasaría a ser tipo char.

Debe ser una tontería pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo. Como sería?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma natural de tratar datos categóricos en R es usando el tipo de dato [`factor`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/factor). Veamos algunos ejemplos:

#### Transformar cadenas a factores o a valores numéricos

```
set.seed(2020)
ejemplo <- sample(niveles, 10, replace = TRUE)

ejemplo
 [1] "Master"        "Master"        "Below College"
 [4] "Below College" "Master"        "College"      
 [7] "Below College" "Doctor"        "College"      
[10] "College"      

# Convertir un conjunto de cadenas en un factor
factor(ejemplo, levels = niveles)
 [1] Master        Master        Below College
 [4] Below College Master        College      
 [7] Below College Doctor        College      
[10] College      
5 Levels: Below College College Bachelor ... Doctor
```

Como `factor` la única diferencia con la variable original, es que internamente todas las cadenas se manejan con un valor numérico según el orden establecido mediante el vector que le pasamos a `levels`. Está característica nos permite transformar luego este factor en sus valores numéricos asociados:

```
# Convertir un variable en un dato numérico 
as.numeric(factor(ejemplo, levels = niveles))
[1] 4 4 1 1 4 2 1 5 2 2
```

El `as.numeric()` nos retornará los levels`, es decir, los números que definen cada etiqueta, mientras` as.character()` nos retornará las etiquetas en sí.

Ahora, si en realidad tienes una variable numérica que quieres transformar en una categórica

#### Transformar valores numéricos a categorías

```
set.seed(2020)
ejemplo <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
ejemplo
[1] 4 4 1 1 4 2 1 5 2 2

factor(ejemplo, levels=1:5, labels = niveles)
 [1] Master        Master        Below College
 [4] Below College Master        College      
 [7] Below College Doctor        College      
[10] College      
5 Levels: Below College College Bachelor ... Doctor
```

`factor()` también te permite transformar un vector numérico en las categorías deseadas, simplemente, debes indicar los `levels` y `labels` que corresponda. Nota además, que no se requiere en ningún caso tener todos los niveles en el vector original. El los ejemplos, el `level=3` no lo tenemos en el vector de origen, pero la "magia" de los factores nos permiten definir este.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias Patricio. Así ha quedado el tema: _employee$Education <- factor(employee$Education, levels=1:5, labels = c("Below College", "College", "Bachelor", "Master", "Doctor"))_

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto una manera muy sencilla de realizarlo utilizando la libraría de stringr que se utiliza para remplazar texto

```
#En caso de no tener intalada la library Stringr
 install.packages("stringr")
 library(stringr)
 
 #Simulamos un set de datos similar al que mencionas
 datos<-data.frame(Education=rep(c("Below College","College","Bachelor","Master","Doctor"),each=9))
 
 #Este vector lo que nos indica a por que valor lo queremos cambiar
 var_cat<-c("Below College"="1","Bachelor"="2","College"="3","Master"="4","Doctor"="5")
  
  #Utilizamos la función str_replace y lo guardamos en una nueva columna llamada Valores
  datos["Valores"]<-str_replace_all(datos$Education,var_cat)

  #Convertimos la columna a numero
  datos["Valores"]<-as.numeric(datos$Valores)
```

El paso final de convertir el resultado a numero es necesario ya que la función de str_replace_all solo funciona con tipo string, y no se puede asignar la variable a tipo numérico.